# Кластерный индекс с некластерным или без

Tags: sql-server

> Объясните, пожалуйста, кластерный индекс в одиночку работает быстрее чем в связке с некластерным?

Comment: Да, поиск по некластерному будет чуть медленнее, потому как надо вначале найти что то в некластерном, потом поднять данные из кластерного по полученной ссылке. Но об этом говорить нет смысла, потому как другого пути просто нет. Предположим у вас в таблице 100 млн записей, кластерный индекс по полю id, т.е. данные физически отсортированы (сильно утрируя) в порядке id. А у нас запрос `select * from table where date='2020-06-01'`. При этом есть некластреный индекс по полю date. Конечно БД выгодно быстро по некластерному найти записи за 1 июня и по ссылкам их получить из кластерного.

Comment: То есть некластерный индекс будет перестраиваться под кластерный при каждом новом создании кластерного индекса даже, если у них столбцы разных типов например int и char?

Comment: А причем тут типы столбцов ? "Кластерный" говорит о том, что в индексе вместо ссылки на строку данных лежит сама строка данных. Если кластерный индекс перестраивается, то все данные таблицы физически перемещаются на диске в новые локации. И конечно во всех остальных индексах необходимо изменить ссылку, потому что она начинает вести на другое значение кластерного ключа